# SQL Group By - Return results as Single Row instead of Multiple (Flatten results)

Tags: sql, group-by, flatten

I have the following job table:

```
job_id | is_full_time | is_short_term 
     1 |      0       |      0
     2 |      0       |      1
     3 |      1       |      0
     4 |      1       |      1
```

I have the following query and I'm getting results in 4 rows.

```
SELECT is_full_time, is_short_term, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FT_Long, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FT_Short,
COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PT_Long, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PT_Short
FROM job
GROUP by is_full_time, is_short_term
```

My results look like this:

```
FT_Long | FT_Short | PT_Long | PT_Short
    1   0     0     0
    0   1     0     0
    0   0     1     0
    0   0     0     1
```

How can I combine this result into a single result row?

I want to see this:

```
 FT_Long | FT_Short | PT_Long | PT_Short
        1   1     1     1
```

Comment: Group by displays the unique values of the columns you are grouping on. That said, you aren't grouping on your aggregate columns so you are getting their entire output. Trying grouping ALL your columns and see what happens.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general this template works well for these situations:

```
SELECT SUM(FT_Long) as FT_Long, SUM(FT_Short) AS FT_Short, SUM(PT_Long) AS PT_Long, SUM(PT_Short) AS PT_Short
FROM
(
  SELECT is_full_time, is_short_term, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FT_Long, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FT_Short,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PT_Long, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PT_Short
  FROM job
  GROUP by is_full_time, is_short_term
) T
```

In this case I believe you will get the same results with the following this will depend on what else is in your data that is requiring the group by in your original query

```
  SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FT_Long, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FT_Short,
  SUM(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PT_Long, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PT_Short
  FROM job
```

Comment: Looks like this took care of it! Thanks a million for the quick and simple reply!

Answer (score 2):

You can safely remove the `GROUP BY` and `SUM` the row instead of counting them

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FT_Long, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FT_Short,
    SUM(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PT_Long, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PT_Short
FROM job
```

Comment: For this, I'm seeing the following error: Column 'job.is_full_time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @AdamLevitt which db are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your posted results do not match up with your select statement.  Specifically, your select statement includes is_full_time and is_short_term.  If you remove them from your select, then you can remove them from your group by.

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FT_Long, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FT_Short,
COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PT_Long, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PT_Short
FROM job
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The SUM() can be used to calculate the sum of the columns

```
SELECT is_full_time, is_short_term, 
SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS FT_Long, 
SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 1 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS FT_Short,
SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS PT_Long, 
SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN is_full_time = 0 AND is_short_term = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS PT_Short
FROM job
GROUP by is_full_time, is_short_term
```